# Delayed job throwing an error failed with TypeError: can't convert String into Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

Actually I am using the delayed job to run the email process at background. When I called the delay method of delayed_job its insert the record into Delayed::Job table but mails are not going and when I check the delayed_job.log it contains "failed with TypeError: can't convert nil into Hash" error.

UserMailer.rb file contain following code

```
 def welcome_email(user)
    @username = user.name
    setup_email(user)
 end
```

In User controller

```
UserMailer.delay.welcome_email(User.last)
```

But when I removed delay method then mails are going
the code is :

```
UserMailer.welcome_email(User.last).deliver
```

I am not getting why this error is coming withe delay,please help me to find the cause of this issue.

Comment: What is setup_email method doing? Can you share that code?

Answer (score 2):

Check your mailer configuration.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 def welcome_email(user)
  ##access hash in this way user['email']..not using dot operator user.email
  @user=User.find_by_email user['email']
  mail(:to => user['email'], :subject => "Hi #{user['username']},Welcome to mywebsite.com")
end
```

Moreover for `delay` You need to run the `rake jobs:work` task to have a process by Delayed Job work off jobs from that table. Without this, you will not receive any emails.